# DFS Algorithem and Formallization

Tags: algorithms, formal-proofs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple undirected graph with $|V|=4$. Some run of DFS produces a spanning tree in which the root has degree 2.
Claim: $|E|\leq 4$.

Basically I know it's true but I have no idea how to formalize it.
Is there someone here who can give me a formal solution ?

Comment: Hint: let the starting node be $s$, and let $G’$ be the subgraph without $s$. Can $G’$ be connected?

Comment: Yeap. but I'm not sure why this is helping

Comment: Its connected if it has exactly 4 edges